# How to use WindowsIdentity.Impersonate to get the user's login, rather than the ASPNET account

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, impersonation, windows-authentication

I have a web-app that will reside on a production server where I want to get the user's logged in computer name, circa

> DOMAINNAME/USERNAME

Many people have told me that I must use Impersonation/Delegation in order to get this, but no details beyond that have been provided.  Originally, my tests used:

```
Response.Write("HttpContext: " & HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name & " \n")
Response.Write("Windows Identity: " & WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name & " \n")
Response.Write("Thread: " & Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name & " \n")
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
Response.Write(User.Identity.Name)
```

Which yields valid results on my local cassini server, but not when published.  Adding the following line:

```
Dim ctx As WindowsImpersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero)
```

changes the WindowsIdentity to

> SERVERNAME\ASPNET

However, I wish for the current user's (not the server's) username.  How can I manipulate the impersonation class to give me this?

**EDIT:**
The solution provided, in the comments by Heinzi, seems to be correct.  However, I believe this is IE6 only.  The company I work for may be moving to IE8 in the near future and I wish to ensure functionality across IE 6/7/8 at the very least.  Is this possible?

Comment: You've set up IIS for Integrated Authentication, right?

Comment: I've tried using Integrated Authentication on my localhost/project..., but this prompted me for my username and password each time.  Since I am working a corporate environment, I do not have direct access to the IIS settings of the production box.  If I'm sure that switching this setting will work, I can ask for it switched, but it didn't seem to solve anything on my localhost.

Comment: About localhost: If you are asked about username and password, it is possible that your Internet Explorer is not configured to pass on your Windows credentials. Make sure that you are in the "Intranet" zone (look at the lower right-hand corner of the status bar).

Comment: It should be default, it's just that Internet Explorer sometimes has trouble detecting the Intranet zone.

Comment: Mark, one clarification question: You write that you don't have direct access to the IIS. Is the IIS in the same domain?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I responded from my colleague's computer earlier so I've deleted that and answering again here.  The application will reside on servername.domainname.com/applicationname.  Does this imply that the IIS is on the same domain?

Comment: Not necessarily. What does "whoami /fqdn" on your development machine output? If it's "...domainname.com", that might be an indication. Another test might be to access servername.domainname.com/applicationname with Internet Explorer and have a look at the zone.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  The domain resolves nicely with IE6 and gives desired functionality.  However, it seems that IE7/8 still request username/password credentials.

Comment: Does IE7/8 recognize your production server as "Intranet"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- activate Windows Integrated Authentication in IIS,
- turn off anonymous users either in IIS or in your web.config file (`<authorization>` section),
- add `<identity impersonate="true" />` in the `<system.web>` section of your web.config.

**EDIT**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589289) shows relevant parts from the web.config.